# Changing bootstrap panel color using sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, panel

I'm pretty new to using both twitter bootstrap and sass.  I am trying to modify the background color of the panel-header in bootstrap using a .sass file in a rails application.

This is the bootstrap css according to inspect element:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
```

and here's what I'm trying in my sass file to change the color

```
.panel-default
  .panel-heading
    background-color: #fdf1d8
```

I'm wondering if the problem has to do with the selector used in the bootstrap css?  I don't know how that translates to indented sass. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using [Bootstrap-SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will spit out the following:

```
.panel-default .panel heading { 
  background-color: #fdf1d8; 
}
```

`>` is very specific, so you should use it, too:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: #fdf1d8`
}
```